# How to use Expo AppAuth module with IdentityServer4

Tags: react-native, identityserver4, expo, appauth

I am trying to use the Expo AppAuth module to do authentication using IdentityServer4 in react native. Cant seem to get the redirectUri settings right. I'm getting an 'invalid redirect uri" error when i redirect to identityServer.

This is my client on identityserver

```
return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "client",
                    ClientId = "client",
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequireConsent = true,
                    RedirectUris =
                    {
                        "host.exp.Exponent" //Is this correct
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile"},

                }
            };
```

My config settings for AppAuth are

```
const config = {
    issuer: 'http://localhost:3000',
    clientId: 'client',
    scopes: ['profile', 'openid'],
    redirectUri: "host.exp.Exponent"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `redirectUri` as the address value.

AppAuth Definitions:

```js
async function _executeAsync(props: OAuthProps): Promise<TokenResponse> {
  if (!props.redirectUrl) {
    props.redirectUrl = getDefaultOAuthRedirect();
  }
  assertValidProps(props);
  return await ExpoAppAuth.executeAsync(props);
}

export function getDefaultOAuthRedirect(): string {
  return `${ExpoAppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect`;
}
```

Comment: I also have this but i get this when redirected back
Could not load exp://host.exp.exponent